# How to avoid to spin a Sandbox on a Preview Pod during the Sandbox Preview-Release Window

Tags: apex, managed-package, sandbox, pre-release

For uses-cases like a staging-org, where several complex and interacting managed-package upgrades are to be tested, a preview participation is fatal: **we can't install managed packages from current-release packaging orgs into preview sandboxes.** So therefore we need strictly to avoid any participation of Sandbox Previews, because they are show-stoppers.

Now the Preview participation seems to be purely determined by time. According to this http://blogs.salesforce.com/company/2014/07/salesforcecom-winter-15-sandbox-preview-instructions.html all Sandbox creations and refreshes which happend after Jul. 30 and before Aug. 30 has been routed to preview-instances. And this routing-switch perpetuates before all new releases.

As an unfortunate this is really a very long time and we **need to refresh/create current release sandboxes even during this time-frame.**

So my questions are:

- Is the any way to create sandboxes during the Preview-Intervalls (which will be 3/12 or 25% of all the time in a year!) without getting routed into Preview?
- Is there something like a global preview-opt-out if you really can't participate with an Org?

Comment: Have you tried contacting Salesforce support? I can't see anything in the notes that would suggest that you can 'opt-out', but there are a lot of things that Salesforce support can do for you that are not documented.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can request it through Salesforce support, it needs to get escalated to tier 3. I've just confirmed this with Salesforce support.

It isn't documented but basically the earlier you request it the better - I got an email alerting me of the preview instructions so if you acted on getting that you *should* be ok to get the preview cancelled on the particular org.

Comment: Thanks, that sounds promising. Do you know if the request has to be repeated for each single release again and again - or is it a future-proof permanent opt-out for a particular Org?

Comment: It wasn't 100% clear but it was implied the request would be required for each release.

Comment: good to know; what drives us batty is when our fullcopy staging sandbox gets updated but the preview release has sfdc bugs in it - preventing CI/CD from working *!%$@